# Secugen FingerPrint Windows .NET Exception

Tags: .net, x86, device, fingerprint, avcodec

Im using Secugen Fingerprint U20 model, and develop a .NET desktop application, we use “Secugen.FDxSDKPro.Windows dll (ver 1.0.0)” in our application, but sometimes we cannot verify fingerprint and our application constantly closes by itself, when we watch the logs, I will be sharing the function we get the error with you below.

```
 public static SGFingerPrintManager m_FPM = new SGFingerPrintManager();
 Byte[] m_VrfMin;

 SGFPMDeviceInfoParam pInfo = new SGFPMDeviceInfoParam();

 m_ImageWidth = pInfo.ImageWidth;
 m_ImageHeight = pInfo.ImageHeight;


 var fp_image = new Byte[m_ImageWidth * m_ImageHeight];
 Int32 iError = BIOIDReader.m_FPM.GetImage(fp_image);

 if (iError == (Int32)SGFPMError.ERROR_NONE)
 else
     “Failed verify”
```

its sometimes get “Failed verify” , which causes the application to close on its own.

but there is no problem with the device, there is no problem with the driver and it is not a problem that happens all the time, it happens in some devices. The devices are x64 bit Windows 10 installed machines.

Secugen.FDxSDKPro.Windows dll is running as x86 bit, and I'm getting releases as x86, could this be the reason ? There is no x64 version anyway, and when I checked the Windows Event Log I saw an error with avcodec dll, but I couldn't find the source of what caused it.
Can anyone help ?